# How to remove scratches on varnished wooden door?

Tags: scratches

Is there any easy way to make scratches disappear from wooden, varnished doors? Doesn't have to be perfect, I just need to make them hard to spot for someone who doesn't know they're there.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several finish repair products on the market.  You can get most of them from the usual getting spots.

I've had very positive results with "restor a finish", they sell it in multiple colors so you just need to find the one that most closely matches the wood you are working with.   There are also "fill sticks" that are probably better suited to deeper scratches.  Also "Feed-N-Wax" will make a lot of scratches less visible.

Comment: Thanks, gosh these products are expensive. Have you ever come across any cheaper solution that works? Some people said there were impressed by... walnuts (rubbing a peeled walknut against the scratch)

Comment: @drake035: yeah the walnut trick works, the restor a finish is also a varnish though so it will reseal the wood where the scratch is where a walnut wouldn't

Comment: @drake035 note that while one purchase of these repair products may be expensive up front, it's likely to last you the rest of your life, so the per-use cost is pretty low.